# c# taking hours of time to execute

Tags: c#

Code below is taking hours of time to execute. I'm comparing each string from database to calculate N00,N01,N10,N11 parameters. Temp1 is List of type string it consists of more than 5000 words

```
foreach (string ri in temp1)
{
  for (int a3 = 0; a3 < ssl.Count; a3++)
  {
    //for (int tn = 0; tn < tempNam.Count ; tn++)
    //{
        try
        {
          SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='" + ri + "' and ss. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + "=0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s. " +  ssl[a3].ToString()+ "=0", con);
          int im = (int)cmd5.ExecuteScalar();
          if (im == 1)
          {
            gh += 1;
          }
          SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='" + ri + "' and ss. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + "=0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + ">0", con);
          int im1 = (int)cmd6.ExecuteScalar();
          if (im1 == 1)
          {
            gh2 += 1;
          }
          SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='" + ri + "' and ss. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + ">0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + "=0", con);
          int im2 = (int)cmd7.ExecuteScalar();
          if (im2 == 1)
          {
            gh3 += 1;
          }
          SqlCommand cmd8 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='" + ri + "' and ss. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + ">0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s. " + ssl[a3].ToString() + ">0", con);
          int im3 = (int)cmd8.ExecuteScalar();
          if (im3 == 1)
          {
            gh4 += 1;
          }
          if (a3 == (ssl.Count-1))
          {
            SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("update sample set N00=" + gh + " where KeyWord='" + ri + "'", con);
            ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gh = 0;
            SqlCommand ins1 = new SqlCommand("update sample set N01=" + gh2 + " where KeyWord='" + ri + "'", con);
            ins1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gh2 = 0;
            SqlCommand ins2 = new SqlCommand("update sample set N10=" + gh3 + " where KeyWord='" + ri + "'", con);
            ins2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gh3 = 0;
            SqlCommand ins4 = new SqlCommand("update sample set N11=" + gh4 + " where KeyWord='" + ri + "'", con);
            ins4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            gh4 = 0;
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
      // }
    }
  }

  SqlCommand cmd1s = new SqlCommand("select KeyWord from sample", con);
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1s);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "sample");
  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    string dd = dr["KeyWord"].ToString();
    if (dd != "y")
    {
      if (!li.Contains(dd))
      {
        li.Add(dd);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1.2 billion kittens just died...

Comment: Every time you execute a SqlCommand object you're generating unnecessary overhead. It's likely not your issue, but it'll add to it. There's a myriad of optimisation issues - I recommend you take some time out to learn basic database query optimisation... poor kittens.

Comment: Stop hurting my brain. Please refactor that code to something that is more intent revealing, because this code is so hard to understand, that I don’t even want to look at it.

Comment: Upvoted. Yes the code is ugly, but if it gets buried vj4u won't get any help.

Comment: Use variable names that have meaning, not shorthand abbreviations. It's nearly impossible for other devs to read your code and keep track of that "a3" or "gh4" are supposed to be.

Comment: @Steven: someone who writes code like this doesn't know what refactor means yet, just cry on the inside and hope in a year or two he doesn't write code like this anymore..

Comment: And calling "please help its urgent" won't make us help you faster.

Comment: Upvoted for prime example of `fresh programmer` code.

Answer (score 11):

Put an index on `Sample.KeyWord`. This would make this a hell of a lot faster.

As with Anthony's comment below, there's a lot wrong with this code. The index is what I'm guessing is taking the most time, but you should read these topics as well:

- [Evil Practices - Swallowing Exceptions](http://blog.mohammadjalloul.com/blogs/mo/archive/2009/12/13/evil-practices-swallowing-exceptions.aspx)
- [The SqlParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)
- [The using() construct](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx) - This applies to any object implementing the `IDisposable` interface.
- [.NET Naming Conventions and Programming Standards - Best Practice](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices) - It is crucial to have meaningful names at the **very** least.

---

Look here for creating indices: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: ...and learn about using statements, reusing objects rather than having x billion times 4 copies, and "hey, look, is that a swallowed exception I see?"

Comment: @Anthony - Etc. Etc. Etc. :P This could help teach a class the way it is. @vj4u - updated with a link.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your code is very hard to understand with the variables named the way they are. 
I refactored your query for readability, moved to reusing a single SqlCommand (two in total if you count the one outside of the loop) and removed the extra queries.

I'm guessing the poor performance is tied to lack of object reuse, replication of effort with your queries, and you're probably throwing exceptions left and right and the try/catch is causing the stack to unwind every time you throw an exception! Check the output pane for debug information or set a breakpoint on the line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString());`. **Unwinding the stack will kill execution time.**

I'm not sure if you're using poor variable names, or if you obfuscated your code, but you should really thing about putting meaningful variable names in code you need help with.

*I'm positive that there is alot more you can do to optimize your code, but I'd take care of reusing the SqlCommand, removing repeated queries, and correctly handling your exception handling first.*

```
foreach (string ri in temp1)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < ssl.Count; index++)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command;
            string query;

            query = string.Format("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='{0}' and ss.{1}=0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s.{1}=0", ri, ssl[index].ToString());
            command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                gh++;
                gh3++;
            }

            query = string.Format("select count(*) from sample s inner join   sample ss on ss.KeyWord='{0}' and ss.{1}=0 and s.KeyWord='y' and s.{1}>0", ri, ssl[index].ToString());
            command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
            {
                gh2++;
                gh4++;
            }

            if (index == (ssl.Count-1))
            {
                query = string.Format("update sample set N00={0} where KeyWord='{1}'", gh.ToString(), ri);
                command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                gh = 0;

                query = string.Format("update sample set N01={0} where KeyWord='{1}'", gh2.ToString(), ri);
                command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                gh2 = 0;

                query = string.Format("update sample set N10={0} where KeyWord='{1}'", gh3.ToString(), ri);
                command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                gh3 = 0;

                query = string.Format("update sample set N11={0} where KeyWord='{1}'", gh4.ToString(), ri);
                command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                gh4 = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select KeyWord from sample", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "sample");
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string KeywordCell = dr["KeyWord"].ToString();
    if (KeywordCell != "y")
    {
        if (!li.Contains(KeywordCell))
        {
            li.Add(KeywordCell);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One *minor* thing to try once you've dealt with the larger issues pointed out by the others...

You're calculating `ssl[a3].ToString()` 8 times for each time through the inner loop.  That's 40,000 times for each value of a3.  You can pre-calculate the string values of each item in a3 and store them in a List before the outer loop.  Then, instead of iterating over the index off ssl in the inner loop, use a foreach on the values of your pre-calculated list of strings.

If you do this, you will need to move the code in the `if (a3 == (ssl.Count-1))` out of the inner loop to the end of the outer loop.